# Loop While & Break in Java

Tags: java

When the user enters several names, I would like to break only if the user enters the value `end`.

I am trying this but it doesn't work.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    String name = "";

    while(name != "end"){
      System.out.print("Enter name : " + name);
      name = sc.next();
      if (name == "end") {
     break;
     }
   }
```

Comment: don't compare String (or any Object's) values by ==.

Comment: Also, use do/while instead of while, because you want the loop to execute at least once: `do { /* ... */ name = sc.next(); } while (!name.equals("end"));`

Comment: In java programming language. use .equals method to compare objects. To provide custom method to compare objects of same class, override the .equals method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

Try the below:

```
 String name = "";

    while(!name.equals("end")){
      System.out.print("Enter name : " + name);
      name = sc.next();
      if (name.equals("end")) {
     break;
     }
   }
```